# AppGameKit Basic - How to spawn more sprites and make them move

Tags: basic

My Variables:

```
ballX = GetSpritex(BALL)
ballY = GetSpritey(BALL)
```

My Ball:

```
LoadImage(BALL,"BALL.png")
CreateSprite(BALL, BALL)
SetSpritePosition(BALL,5, 0)
SetSpriteSize(BALL,Width/25,Height/25)
```

I'm wondering how I can make the ball spawn all over the map 25 times and move randomly
I'm using AppGameKit(AGK) in Basic

Answer (score 0):

you could do ......

```
global Ball as integer[24] //0-24 = 25

LoadImage(BALL[0],"BALL.png")
CreateSprite(BALL[0], BALL)
SetSpritePosition(BALL[0],5, 0)
SetSpriteSize(BALL[0],Width/25,Height/25)

for i = 1 to ball.length  //1 to 24 since we created [0] already
    ball[i] = clonesprite(BALL[0]) // copies everything about the sprite 
next i
```

all the balls will be on top of eachother so youll have to change the positions of course